# React formik select value not bind in array

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am creating form using formik and I want age list 1 to 100 in dropdown i am showed but one submit value are not working

codesandox:
https://nmsje.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the following code from

```
<MenuItem key={item} value={item.value}>
  {item}
</MenuItem>;
```

To:

```
<MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
  {item}
</MenuItem>;
```

Items are just plain numbers not object, so there is no `value` property in them. I'm not sure why it's not throwing an error though.